# Issue testing a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

This is my directive spec file. I'm using angular 6.

```
import { Component, DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { KeyboardInputDirective } from './keyboard-input.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'kiosk-app-test-component',
  template: `<input type="text" name="wu-input" class="wu-input" id="standard" [kioskAppKeyboardInput]="'true'">`
})
class TestStubComponent { }


describe('Directive: KeyboardInputDirective', () => {
  let component: TestStubComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestStubComponent>;
  let directiveEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestStubComponent, KeyboardInputDirective],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestStubComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(KeyboardInputDirective));
    });

  }));

  fit('should create an instance', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(directiveEl).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

I'm getting below error continuously.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
```

If i console `fixture.debugElement` value it is always null.
Any help is really appreciated.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name-xyz",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "$(npm bin)/ng",
    "start:web": "$(npm bin)/ng serve web",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^6.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.45",
    "angular": "^1.6.9",
    "angular4-translate": "^1.3.5",
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fetch-intercept": "^2.3.0",
    "fingerprintjs2": "1.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "3.2.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-remove-code": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "husky": "^3.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-logger": "^3.3.12",
    "ngx-mask": "^6.1.3",
    "ngx-page-scroll-core": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-popper": "^5.1.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "protractor-axe-report-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "save": "^2.3.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.21.4",
    "systemjs-plugin-babel": "0.0.25",
    "virtual-keyboard": "^1.28.4",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.118",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-i18n-lint": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-tap": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to move **fixture.detectChanges();** inside your **describe** as follows.

```
describe('Directive: KeyboardInputDirective', () => {
  let component: TestStubComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestStubComponent>;
  let directiveEl: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestStubComponent, KeyboardInputDirective],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestStubComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(KeyboardInputDirective));
    });

  }));
```

Hope this helps, let me know still if you are facing issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help but tried it getting the same error.

Comment: can you add your pacakge.json content, your code is working fine for me

Comment: Edited the original question posted.

Comment: It works fine for me, can you try reproducing it on stackblitz ? you can refer this demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-example

Answer (score 0):

`TestBed.compileComponents` is not needed in this case but `fixture.detectChanges` needs to be called before querying the `HTML` element. You could address (query) the `input` element directly and interact with it in your test to see if the directive works correctly. Not knowing what your directive really does, the test below obviously needs to be adapted to make it work for you.

```
describe('Directive: KeyboardInputDirective', () => {

  let component: TestStubComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestStubComponent>;
  let inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestStubComponent, KeyboardInputDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('INPUT');
  });

  ...

  it('#keydown should ...', fakeAsync(() => {

    // given
    spyOn(inputElement, 'setSelectionRange');
    inputElement.value = 'abc';
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '' });

    // when
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    tick();

    // then
    expect(inputElement.setSelectionRange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 3);
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but getting this error: ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null``